# How to keep surrounding content of cropped image if minimum size would not be met using opencv2?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, crop

We're using some code like this to crop images to just the subject's faces - but the output images are sometimes too small for their intended use.

For example, we need output images to be 600x600 pixels at minimum, but the code can yield crops smaller than this due to the face taking up a smaller area, eg 528x528. Is there a way to ensure a minimum size?

I have to admit that I'm not entirely sure how this snippet of code really works behind the scenes. Our code looks like this:

```py
def crop_single_image(inputName, outputName):
    # Read the input image
    img = cv2.imread(inputName)

    # Convert into grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    print(outputName)
    # Draw rectangle around the faces and crop the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print({x, y, w, h})
        faces = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        cv2.imwrite(outputName, faces)
```

Comment: Either resize or pad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @fmw42 but can you expand on it? Those words alone are not enough to lead me to the right path.

Comment: You have two choices to get the image to the size you want: 1) resize the image so that the smallest dimension or largest dimension match the desired size and crop or pad depending upon which you chose or 2) just pad the remainder of your image with some color or transparency to the size you desire.